# Weird values while debugging values in Unity

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

I found out while debugging floats and stuff in Unity the values are sometimes off. I.e. I have a float called currentSpeed and when the player is moving this is a value and when he is not it is 0. The problem is when debugging this value while walking the following happens; i.e. 1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1. I found out this is happening with multiple values and Vectors. The weird thing is, when my framerate is lower it doesn't happen (i.e. while having the player selected in the inspector the framerate drops from 60 to 48). I'm using Unity 2018.3 and have no clue how to fix this. I hope someone can help me.

Edit (added code):

```
void Move(Vector2 inputDir, bool running)
{
    if (inputDir != Vector2.zero)
    {
        // When the player is not pushing we can create a moving direction
        if (!playerIsPushing)
        {
            float targetRotation = Mathf.Atan2(inputDir.x, inputDir.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cameraT.eulerAngles.y;
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetRotation, ref turnSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(turnSmoothTime));
        }
    }

    float targetSpeed = ((running) ? runSpeed : movementSpeed) * inputDir.magnitude;
    currentSpeed = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentSpeed, targetSpeed, ref speedSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(speedSmoothTime));

    velocityY += Time.deltaTime * gravity;

    Vector3 velocity = transform.forward * currentSpeed + Vector3.up * velocityY;

    // Here we cap the players velocity to a maximum speed. In this case the runSpeed. This means the player can never exceed the runSpeed.
    if (velocity.x > runSpeed)
    {
        velocity.x = runSpeed;
    }

    if (velocity.x < -runSpeed)
    {
        velocity.x = -runSpeed;
    }

    if (velocity.z > runSpeed)
    {
        velocity.z = runSpeed;
    }

    if (velocity.z < -runSpeed)
    {
        velocity.z = -runSpeed;
    }

    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    currentSpeed = new Vector2(controller.velocity.x, controller.velocity.z).magnitude;

    // Debugging the players velocity
    Debug.Log(currentSpeed);

    float animationSpeedPercent = ((running) ? currentSpeed / runSpeed : currentSpeed / movementSpeed * .5f);
```

Edit 2: I have tested some more and found out my pushforce isn't framerate independant. During pushing an object in my game I see the weird values while debugging i.e. 1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1. I'm working with a CharacterController so adding force to a rigidbody is done via script.

```
void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    Rigidbody body = hit.collider.attachedRigidbody;

    if (body == null || body.isKinematic)
        return;

    if (hit.moveDirection.y < -.3f)
        return;

    Vector3 pushDirection = new Vector3(hit.moveDirection.x, 0, hit.moveDirection.z);
    body.velocity = pushForce * pushDirection;
}
```

Might this be the issue for the weird values?

Comment: where is the code of the problem?

Comment: I dont think it’s a part of code to be fair, as this is happening accros the entire project with different floats and values.

Comment: Is your movement speed framerate independant (modified by `Time.DeltaTime`)? Doing this will ensure it has the same behvaiour across different framerates. If you're using floats that are off by a little bit it could also be due to "Floating point precision". Please add the code you use to set currentSpeed and how you log it.

Comment: So it should have Time.deltaTime? I will update my question with the corresponding code.